# Does one plus phone dosent allow to start bluetooth scan from background

Tags: android, bluetooth

So i have an app which starts Bluetooth scan to detect near by devices, in the foreground it works fine, then what i do is, i take the app to the background and turn off the bluetooth and location off, then after few 1-2 minutes i turn on the bluetooth and location,(i do have a bluetooth state change listner), so when this happens the bluetooth state change detects this event and starts the Bluetooth scan, but unfortunately, it does not work

in short i am trying to say is Bluetooth start scan works when called when app is in foreground, but dosent work when app is in background

this behavior i dont get in other non one plus phone.

Is there a workaround for this?